# How to fix SyntaxError: fields are not currently supported error in JavaScript, Firefox?

Tags: javascript, firefox

I've just been learning JavaScript, and I'm fairly new to coding. I was learning about properties and fields and for some reason Firefox won't run if my class contains fields.

Here's some code that gives the error in the title.

```
class Animal {
  _paws = true;

  get paws() {
    return _paws;
  }
}

let cat = new Animal();

console.log(cat.paws);
```

Answer (score 17):

Firstly, there's an error in your code. It should be `this._paws` in the `return` statement.

```js
class Animal {
  _paws = true;

  get paws() {
    return this._paws;       // Correct here.
  }
}

let cat = new Animal();

console.log(cat.paws);
```

Since this answer was posted, Firefox has gained support for public (and private) class field declarations. The [Chrome Platform Status](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/6001727933251584) documentation on this is out-of-date, as can be seen by the present `FIXED` status of the [Mozilla bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1499448) it links to.

The equivalent [Mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes#Field_declarations) shows support for public field declarations from version 69. By the way, **this** chart is also partly out-of-date, as in fact [Firefox Android has the same level of support as Firefox Desktop](https://github.com/mdn/browser-compat-data/issues/7430).

For production use of this feature you should bear in mind this caveat from the Mozilla documentation:

> Public and private field declarations are an [experimental feature (stage 3)](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields) proposed at [TC39](https://tc39.github.io/beta/), the JavaScript standards committee. Support in browsers is limited, but the feature can be used through a build step with systems like [Babel](https://babeljs.io/).

Both developer resource sites cited above indicate that Safari still lacks support for this feature (although given their incompleteness, who can say whether this is still accurate).

Comment: It is July 2020 now, still there is no support for public and private field declarations in Javascript. I am finding it hard to do OOP in JS. Are there any alternative methods to achieve public fields? I am trying to declare valid static constants used by all other classes. `class MEDIA { IMAGE = 0; AUDIO = 1; VIDEO = 2; }` and use them like `MEDIA.IMAGE` or `MEDIA.AUDIO` in other classes, but I find it difficult with this limitation.

Comment: @BReddy Use TypeScript in that case. JavaScript doesn't support OOP or types.

Comment: @BReddy you may know that recent Firefox does now support fields, including static fields so you can declare `class MEDIA { static IMAGE = 0; }` and so on. Of course this is bleeding-edge (current LTS release does not have it yet) so not a good idea for production. You can always use the old class syntax in the meantime.

Comment: @Headbank, Thanks for the updated information. I will keep an eye on this feature.

Comment: Thanks @Headbank. Nice to know. Would you like to edit the answer and add it? I'll add your credits too.

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman Happy to do so - I think I would remove the chromestatus.com citation and screenshot and simply replace with saying that public field declarations are now supported from firefox 69. (The following section from developer.mozilla.org then serves as a caveat.) If that works for you I'll perform it when I get a mInute.

Comment: @Headbank Wow, you could have just done it. I trust you, people trust your thought. It's open source. Thanks again in advance. Please carry on!  Feel free to add something like (Credits: Headbank) or whatever you feel...

Comment: @Headbank Thank you so much. You're awesome! 

Comment: No problem :) Now all we need is someone with the details on Safari...

Answer (score 0):

Just do this for a quick fix:

```
class Animal {
  // _paws = true; Remove this line.

  // Initialize your private fields in constructor instead
  constructor() {
    this._paws;
  }

  get paws() {
    return this._paws; // Must use this._fieldName to reference
  }
}

let cat = new Animal();

console.log(cat.paws);
```

Note that private field is still in the experimental stage on most browsers except Google Chrome.